# NameError: global name 'stealth' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm very new to programming (so sorry if I don't present this problem right).
This is from LPTHW Exercise 36:

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex36.py", line 329, in <module>
    start()
  File "ex36.py", line 149, in start
    arena()
  File "ex36.py", line 161, in arena
    if stealth == True:
NameError: global name 'stealth' is not defined
```

My Assumption:
I thought 'stealth' was defined in the previous function, start(), but the definition didn't carry over to arena().  How do I fix it, and why doesn't 'stealth' from 1 function carry over to another function?

My Code (text-based game in progress):

```
    from sys import argv

    script, enemy = argv
    ...
    def start():
        print """ Choose a skill to train in
        """
        stealth = False
        gun = False
        knife = False
        heal = False
        skill = raw_input("> ")

        if 'gun' in skill:
            print """
            """
            gun = True
            skill = gun
        ...
        else:
            dead()

        arena()

    def arena():
        print """ You enter the arena.  Will you:
        hide, hunt for food, or search for water?
            """

        path = raw_input("> ")

        if "hide" in path:
            print """ Hide
            """

            if stealth == True:
                print """ Witness
                """
                witness()
            else:
                battle()
        ...
        else:
            print """ Dead
            """
            dead()
start()
```

All advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe the variable is so stealthy that Python can't see it.

Comment: @BrenBarn that or its scope is just in `start` and not accessible from  `arena`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables defined locally in one function have local scope and are not automatically accessible within another, disjunct function. You might want to consider passing `stealth` to `arena` when called from `start`, e.g. `arena(stealth)`, and then `stealth` would be defined as a parameter of `arena`, i.e.

```
def arena(stealth):
```